# Either generate a component or drive signal with input

Tags: vhdl

I am trying to create an architecture that has the following behaviour:

```
entity component1 is
    generic (
        debounce_ticks          : natural range 0 to natural'high
    );
    port (
        rst                     : in    STD_LOGIC;
        clk                     : in    STD_LOGIC;
        sclk                    : in    STD_LOGIC;
        [...]              
    );
end component1;
architecture Behavioral of component1 is
     signal sclk_debounced       : STD_LOGIC;
[...]
begin
debouncer:
    if debounce_ticks > 0 generate
        sclk_debouncer : entity work.static_debouncer
        generic map (
            debounce_ticks => debounce_ticks
        )
        port map (
            clk => clk,
            pulse_in => sclk,
            pulse_out => sclk_debounced
        );
    else --Or something
       sclk_debounced <= sclk
    end generate debouncer;
[..]
end Behavioral;
```

So, I have this signal, which I want to either just connect to an input or loop trough a component, based on a generic.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: `component` is a reserved word in VHDL and can not be used as an identifier (entity name).

Comment: That is an error in the example, not in the actual implementation I am trying to make.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `if generate` statement does not support an `else` clause, so you need to invert the check to simulate an `else`. Also you need a second label for the other `if generate`.

```
begin
debouncer:
    if debounce_ticks > 0 generate
        sclk_debouncer : entity work.static_debouncer
        generic map (
            debounce_ticks => debounce_ticks
        )
        port map (
            clk => clk,
            pulse_in => sclk,
            pulse_out => sclk_debounced
        );
    end generate debouncer;
no_debouncer:
    if debounce_ticks <= 0 generate
       sclk_debounced <= sclk
    end generate no_debouncer;
[...]
```

Comment: `The if generate statement does not support an else clause` - that's not correct. VHDL-2008 adds elsif and else branches to an if-generate statement and it adds case-generate statements. the correct sequence of keywords is `else [ alternative_label : ] generate`.

Answer (score 0):

You need two changes:

1. `component` is a reserved word and can't be used as an identifier.
2. the reserved word `generate` is missing after `else`

**Renamed entity:**

```
entity component1 is
  generic (
    debounce_ticks          : natural range 0 to natural'high
  );
  port (
    rst                     : in    STD_LOGIC;
    clk                     : in    STD_LOGIC;
    sclk                    : in    STD_LOGIC;
    -- [...]              
  );
end entity component1;
```

**Fixed generate statement:**

```
architecture Behavioral of component1 is
  signal sclk_debounced       : STD_LOGIC;
  -- [...]
begin
  debouncer: if debounce_ticks > 0 generate
    sclk_debouncer : entity work.static_debouncer
      generic map (
        debounce_ticks => debounce_ticks
      )
      port map (
        clk => clk,
        pulse_in => sclk,
        pulse_out => sclk_debounced
      );
  else generate --Or something
    sclk_debounced <= sclk
  end generate debouncer;
  -- [..]
end architecture Behavioral;
```